# prettyPhoto working perfectly on Dreamweaver; but not working online on any browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, dreamweaver, prettyphoto

**RESOLVED**

I've uploaded everything in the right direction to the ftp and tested several times. And I2ve also checked if there were any uppercase-lowercase problems with the folder names. What is the problem? Am I missing something? I'm using mac by the way.

Here's one of the pages that i'm using prettyPhoto: http://www.gulcebaycik.com/works-design/bade.html

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your paths to the prettyPhoto JavaScript and CSS generate a 403 errors. Fix that and you should be fine.

```
../scripts/prettyPhoto/js/jquery.prettyPhoto.js
../scripts/prettyPhoto/css/prettyPhoto.css
```